# can not connect to appfog mysql by sequel pro

Tags: cloud-hosting, appfog

How do you connect appfog database (mysql) to GUI database app, sequel pro for example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your using `af tunnel` the host will be localhost (127.0.0.1) on port 10000

https://docs.appfog.com/services/tunneling#3rd-party-tools

UPDATED:

In a terminal run `af tunnel <service name>` and choose option `1: none`. Leave the terminal window open and then open sequel pro and create a new db connection using the username, password, dbname provided by af tunnel. Use `localhost` port 10000 as your host and port.

Comment: Just imagine you want to connect appfog database with a UI database app, sequel pro for example, how do you do it?